# Where is the documentation for writing Eclipse toolchain plugins?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, solaris, dbx, cc

We're running Solaris 2.10 and using the native Solaris build tools (CC & dbx), for which there is no support in Eclipse 8.  I up to writing the plugins to support these tools, but I'm having a hard time finding the documentation of the interface for the plugins needed by Eclipse to make this happen.  A sample project (or even the source for the existing plugins) would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the Oracle product which contains dbx and CC is "Oracle Solaris Studio".  As far as I know, Oracle doesn't publish a spec for the interface used in Solaris Studio IDE.  The Oracle IDE is based on NetBeans.  Some of the modules which are used in Solaris Studio IDE are also available in the open source NetBeans C/C++ download.  But some are proprietary.  Hopefully it helps you to know that there is not just a document which you cannot find.  The information is currently not made public.

Comment: I'm not looking for the documentation for the Oracle Solaris Studio - I'm looking for the Eclipse documentation that describes the interface my tools need to support in order to integrate with Eclipse.  I figure I can write a screen-scraping text parser that will provide the proper Eclipse plugin by wrapping around the Solaris tools.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I misread your question.  I don't know where to find Eclipse documentation, but I think it's open source, so downloading the source code for the Eclipse C/C++ Development environment would be a good start.